# Login with Facebook-app using nativescript-plugin-firebase failed with no error #ios

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication, nativescript, facebook-login

When I login my app with the "Login with Facebook" and choosing 
"Login with the Facebook app" (as in Image), 
after returning to my app, it has no reaction.

However, if I choose "Login with Phone Number or Email Address", it can successfully authenticate using firebase-nativescript authentication.
[image]
This is what I have found: 
https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/issues/577
It stated that it's the version problem.
However, my version is the version stated with no problem.

My current versions:

```
nativescript, tns-ios: "5.2.0",
nativescript-plugin-firebase: "8.3.2",
```

ios Pod:

```
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.38.0'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.38.0'
```

This is my Delegate:

```
if(app.ios) {
  const FBSdkDelegate = (function (_super) {
    __extends(FBSdkDelegate, _super);
    function FBSdkDelegate() {
        _super.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    FBSdkDelegate.prototype.applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions = (app, launchOptions) => {
      return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions(app, launchOptions);
    };
    FBSdkDelegate.prototype.applicationOpenURLSourceApplicationAnnotation = (app, url, sourceApplication, annotation) => {
      return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().applicationOpenURLSourceApplicationAnnotation(app, url, sourceApplication, annotation);
    };
    FBSdkDelegate.prototype.applicationDidBecomeActive = (app) => {
      FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp();
    };
    FBSdkDelegate.ObjCProtocols = [UIApplicationDelegate];
    return FBSdkDelegate;
  })(UIResponder);

  app.ios.delegate = FBSdkDelegate;
}
```

Comment: Is that when you use login with app the login promise never hits the success neither failure block?

Comment: Does it return any logs like "login cancelled"?

Comment: @Manoj . I checked it and the failure block shows 'login canceled'

Comment: @vann_goh Oh yes. You got the same problem too?

Comment: may you provide your AppDelegate? let's see what's going on..

Comment: @vann_goh Edited, let's have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove the `app.ios.delegate = FBSdkDelegate` as the code below

```
if(app.ios) {
  const FBSdkDelegate = (function (_super) {
    __extends(FBSdkDelegate, _super);
    function FBSdkDelegate() {
        _super.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    FBSdkDelegate.prototype.applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions = (app, launchOptions) => {
      return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions(app, launchOptions);
    };
    FBSdkDelegate.prototype.applicationOpenURLSourceApplicationAnnotation = (app, url, sourceApplication, annotation) => {
      return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().applicationOpenURLSourceApplicationAnnotation(app, url, sourceApplication, annotation);
    };
    FBSdkDelegate.prototype.applicationDidBecomeActive = (app) => {
      FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp();
    };
    FBSdkDelegate.ObjCProtocols = [UIApplicationDelegate];
    return FBSdkDelegate;
  })(UIResponder);
}
```

The similar issues may be found here
https://github.com/AntonioCuevaUrraco/nativescript-facebook-login/issues/27

Hope this helps!